# ajax query on secondary page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

### Background

I've read through several posts and tutorials here on AJAX, and I've gotten it to work great - on **one** page, but I'm still new to utilizing AJAX so I hit a rough spot that I can't understand how to fix.

I have my main page, **ajaxtest.php** which contains a drop-down with this code:

```
<a>
<?php
include('./db.php');
$PM = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT PMName FROM report WHERE PMname <> '' ORDER BY PMName ASC");
?>
<select name="PMName" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($PM)) {
$selected = array_key_exists('PMName', $_POST) && $_POST['PMName'] == $row[0] ? ' selected' : '';
printf(" <option value='%s' %s>%s</option>\n", $row[0], $selected, $row[0]);
}
?></select></a>
```

which pulls this function:

```
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
      if (str !==".PM") {
        if (str=="") {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
          return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Sending the selection from the database off to my second page, **getuser.php**.

The user then sees the rest of the initial page populated with the results of getuser.php, which contains the bulk of my code and the HTML tables populated with the SQL info.

**This is working fine.**

### Issue

My issue stems from the fact that once (and pardon my lack of technical jargon,) getuser.php is populated into the `<div>` that is inside of ajaxtest.php, I can't utilize any other JavaScript or AJAX functions or the entire page just refreshes as if I were to reload ajaxtest.php again from scratch and it puts me back to the initial blank screen with the dropdown menu.

On getuser.php, within the `<form>` that surrounds the entire table, there is a submit button:

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="test()">
```

and

```
<input class="button" name="update"<?= $LineID ?>" type="submit" id="update" value="UPDATE">
```

and this is supposed to link to my JavaScript test() function that simply reads:

```
function test() {
alert("yo");
}
```

but when I click the button, the entire page refreshes instead of executing this function.  Why is this?

**If I manually go to `localhost/getuser.php?q=John%20Doe` instead of "having this page load inside of my ajaxtest.php `<div>`" and click the button, it works just fine** and I get the JavaScript alert to pop up.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: JavaScript / jQuery is not 'aware' of the dynamically loaded elements. You can counter that by using the `on()` method, with [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I don't think this problem has anything to do with ajax. Your form is submitting just like any other form would when you click the submit button without an event handler that prevents the submit.

Comment: I know this is like... a stackoverflow death request... but can you point me in the direction of how to use event handlers properly?  I don't know what they are.  The first few google results were a TON of reading, as is the link above that Jay posted.  I `want` to learn, but any additional direction you could provide regarding something a bit more specific would be greatly appreciated so I know where to look in these pages.

Comment: `onsubmit="return test();"` and make sure `test()` is returning `false`.

Comment: Hmm... it's still refreshing the entire page.  I have `<form method="POST" onsubmit="return test()">` and inside the JS function I have `function test() {
alert("yo");
return false;
}`

Comment: add `action="javascript:;"`, do you see any errors in your console after?

Comment: how do I look at the console? I'm using Chrome load this.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

Comment: What's interesting is that it's telling me this error is taking place on ajaxtest.php, not on getuser.php.  I moved the function from existing on getuser.php over to ajaxtest.php and now it works!  Thanks for all your help, and for pointing me in the right direction, and for teaching me I can debug with the javascript: action :)

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the function `test()` to return false

```
function test() {alert("yo"); return false}
```

and change the line

`<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="test()">`

into

`<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return test()">`

Now it shouldn't refresh the page. Function used in `onsubmit` needs to return true or false.

Comment: Yup, that is exactly what I have, but the page is still refreshing.  Just thinking here - would it matter if my <script> is in the header?  The exact text that I have is `<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return test()">` and `<script>
function loadXMLDoc() { alert("yo"); return false; } </script>`  As I stated before, if I load the getuser.php page, it works just fine...